# How to use "void sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)" of "algorithm" header file inside a class

Tags: c++

I am working on a code and unable to use `sort()` method from inside a class.

```
class MyClass {
    struct MyStruct {
        ...
    } MyStructArr[10];

    void fun() {
        ...  // setting values of MyStructArr
        sort(MyStructArr, MyStructArr + 10, cmp);     // !ERROR!
    }

    int cmp(struct MyStruct a, struct MyStruct b) {
        ...
    }
};
```

But same code is working without class

```
struct MyStruct {
   ...
} MyStructArr[10];

int main() {
    ...  // setting values of MyStructArr
    sort(MyStructArr, MyStructArr + 10, cmp); 
    return 0;
}

int cmp(struct MyStruct a, struct MyStruct b) {
    ...
}
```

I cannot understand why the `sort(...)` with comparison function is not working inside 
the class.
Here is the error :

```
SuffixArray.cpp: In member function 'void SuffixArray_Entry::suffixArray()':
SuffixArray.cpp:31:43: error: no matching function for call to 'sort(SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry [65536], SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
             sort(L, L + N, SuffixArray_cmp);
                                           ^
SuffixArray.cpp:31:43: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,
                 from SuffixArray.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5461:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
     sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last)
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5461:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
SuffixArray.cpp:31:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
             sort(L, L + N, SuffixArray_cmp);
                                           ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,
                 from SuffixArray.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5497:5: note: void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry*; _Compare = int (SuffixArray_Entry::*)(SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry, SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry)]
     sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5497:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'int (SuffixArray_Entry::*)(SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry, SuffixArray_Entry::SuffixArray_entry)'
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/SuffixArray.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Afzalex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestingStore/CPPStoreRoom'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Afzalex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestingStore/CPPStoreRoom'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

*It is error stack trace for my original program. I am using Netbeans with MinGW*

Comment: `cmp` cannot be a non-static member function (and it has no reason to be). Make it static. While you're at it, maybe pass those args as const-references and return `bool` as the specification for `sort` requests.

Comment: Or make it a free function like in your second example (although you would have to expose `MyStruct` publicly from `MyClass` for that to work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare member function `cmp` as a static member function. 
Take into account that it would be much better if the parameters of the function would be references.

The other way is to define a functional object inside the class. For example

```
class MyClass {
    struct MyStruct {
        ...
    } MyStructArr[10];

    struct cmp
    {
        bool operator ()( const struct MyStruct &a, const struct MyStruct &b ) const
        {
            //....
        }
    };

    void fun() {
        ...  // setting values of MyStructArr
        sort(MyStructArr, MyStructArr + 10, cmp());
    }

        ...
```

Also you could define `operator <` for structure `MyStruct`. In this case you could call `std::sort` without a predicate.

Comment: Thank you Vlad. It is working now. Would you please tell me about some documentation where I can read this. (Some recognized or official document)

Comment: @afzalex  I would advice to read "The C++ Standard library" by N.M. Josuttis.

Answer (score 2):

`sort` will have some code that looks like this inside:

```
template <typename Iter, typename Cmp>
void sort(Iter begin, Iter end, Cmp cmp)
{
    // other code
    if (cmp(a, b)) {       // <-- !!!
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Note that to call `cmp` as you originally posted it, you would need something like:

```
myClassInstance->cmp(a, b)
```

but `sort` doesn't have a `MyClass` to call `cmp` on, it only has the things it actually wants to compare.

You can either make your `cmp` not depend on `MyClass` (by making it a nonmember function or by making it `static`) or you can bind an instance of `MyClass` to it by using a lambda or `std::bind` or similar.